# Cómo conectar múltiples (muchas) definiciones de tareas ECS entre 2 clústeres, usando la VPC AWS

Tags: aws, cluster, devcontainer

En ECS tengo 2 cluster, por ahora vamos a llamarle clusterA y clusterB
dentro de cada cluster. tengo corriendo 2 servicios.

- Digamos **clusterA** tiene corriendo a **servicioA1 y servicioA2**
- Digamos **clusterB** tiene corriendo a **servicioB1 y servicioB2**

Entonces cada servicio corre una definicion de tarea, asi mismo cada servicio tiene un balanceador de carga. Hasta ese punto sin problemas, los servicios se comunican por cada DNS. Y todos los servicios estan en una misma **VPC**

Todo funciona bien.

Entonces tenemos a un proveedor de una integracion externa haciendo pruebas de carga de estres. Y tenemos demoras en cada solicitud masiva, por que hace muchas peticiones hacia nuestro **clusterA**, aquel servicioA1(supongamos, por que puede ser servicioA2) hace llamadas hacia el clusterB hacia el servicioB1 mediante el DNS de cada balanceador de carga y tenemos una demora. **Ahora lo que intento hacer es que la comunicacion sea por medio de VPC , por direccion IP privadas de manera interna.**
Es posible?

Comment: Estas en SO en español.. el idioma obligatorio aca es el español.. traduci toda tu pregunta, titulo incluido...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: claro , lo que quiero saber es  ¿Como poder conectar 2 servicios de diferentes cluster entre ellos, mediante una IP privada (VPC)?, dejar de usar los DNS de los balanceadores de carga, teniendo en cuenta que estoy usando Fargate para mis tareas.

Answer (score -1):

Cuando hablas de *cluster* no queda claro si te refieres a ECS o a una serie de máquinas EC2 idénticas lanzadas *a pelo*. Entiendo que lo suyo sería ECS para que el número de máquinas pueda escalar, adaptándose así a la carga que exista en cada momento.

El caso es que cada cluster debería estar gestionado por un balanceador de carga (que sea ALB o NLB ya depende de los requisitos del servicio). Con esto ya tienes una IP específica para conectarse a cada servicio.

Ahora bien, en el caso de que tengas los servicios replicados en diferentes regiones podrías tener un nodo de Global Accelerator. Este servicio de ofrece una IP única y a nivel interno actua como un balanceador de carga a nivel global. Basta entonces con conectar el GA a los blanaceadores de carga y pasar a usar la IP o el DNS del GA para acceder a los servicios. También podrías usar ROUTE 53 para darle un nombre más elegante al punto de entrada.

En cuanto a usar IPs privadas ... sí, GA es capaz de redirigir el tráfico a las subnets privadas (siempre y cuando esté todo bien configurado)